# How to parse a string as a DOM element in Golang using Colly

Tags: go, web-scraping

I'm new with Go and I am using it with [Colly](https://github.com/gocolly/colly) to **scrape** a website but I am having some problems with the noscript tag because it is not getting parsed just returned as a string so I want to transform that string into a colly HtmlElement to be able to query it as a normal tag.

How can I do that?

The website I want to **scrape** is the **Chrome Web Store**

Answer (score 0):

I have not really found a good way to create a `HTMLElement`, however it is possible that you can convert to a `Document` object, and do the same query execution (this has nothing to do with `gocolly` however)

```
var doc,_ = goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(strings.NewReader("<p><a>Your element</a></p>"))
doc.Filter("your selector here")
```